# Using Arcpy.AddMessage() to list out all shapefiles that were converted in a folder

Tags: arcpy

I currently have code that re-projects all my shapefiles in a folder based off an input shapefile that I select. I will attach the code below. The code runs fine, but I would like the message on the geoprocessor window to say "Projected feature1, feature2, feature3, etc"

I currently can only get the script to list: 
"Projected feature1"
"Projected feature2"
"Projected feature3"

It's basically printing the message for each iteration of the loop but I need it to print each feature class selected.

Attached is my example script below.

```
import arcpy
folderLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
targetShapefile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

try:

    targetDescribe = arcpy.Describe(targetShapefile)
    targetSpatialRef= targetDescribe.spatialReference
    targetSpatialName = targetSpatialRef.Name
    arcpy.env.workspace = folderLocation
    featureList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in featureList:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
        spatialRef = desc.spatialReference
        fcName = spatialRef.Name


        if fcName != targetSpatialName:
            rootName = fc.replace(".shp", "")
            outfc = folderLocation + '\\' + rootName + "_Projected"
            outCS = targetSpatialRef
            arcpy.Project_management(fc, outfc, outCS)
            arcpy.AddMessage("Projected "+ fc)


except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: You could build a list and then AddMessage after they're done. Unfortunately AddMessage adds a carriage return on the end of the line and cannot be stopped. Start with PjList = [] # new blank list then PjList.append(fc) inside the loop then when done arcpy.AddMessage('Projected {}'.format(','.join(PjList))); ','.join converts the entire list to a string comma delim - quite handy!

Comment: Thanks Michael, this helped me a bunch and was exactly what I needed. Didn't think to use the .append option. The join is handy!

Comment: After you've worked that into your code please post, with code, as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

```
import arcpy


folderLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
targetShapefile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

newList = []

try:

    targetDescribe = arcpy.Describe(targetShapefile)
    targetSpatialRef= targetDescribe.spatialReference
    targetSpatialName = targetSpatialRef.Name
    arcpy.env.workspace = folderLocation
    featureList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()


    for fc in featureList:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
        spatialRef = desc.spatialReference
        fcName = spatialRef.Name


        if fcName != targetSpatialName:
            rootName = fc.replace(".shp", "")
            outfc = folderLocation + '\\' + rootName + "_Projected"
            outCS = targetSpatialRef
            arcpy.Project_management(fc, outfc, outCS)
            newList.append(fc)


    arcpy.AddMessage("Projected {}".format(','.join(newList))); ','

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
```